# Why do blinds have two different close options?

Tags: insulation, windows, energy-efficiency, blinds

This hopefully works on this site. It certainly should be DIY, though a rather paltry task.

Why do blinds have two close options? There are two different angles that they can be closed and this seems almost universal on commercial blinds. Is there some sort of ventilation or insulation benefit to closing them with the individual slats angled up vs. down?

Comment: Does the TP go over or does it go under?

Comment: That's just a result of how something rolled in a circular motion can unroll. Not a design decision that costs money for materials, design, and production with no immediately clear justification. At least in my experience the difference in light capacity between the two close options is minimal.

Comment: Some types of louvered blinds can be damaged if closed completely in the "up" direction. Check manufacturer's instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They block the light differently depending on where the sun is, and how much light you want to let in.

Comment: Angled up, let sky light in while blocking view for privacy. Angled down, block sky light while blocking view for privacy. Intermeiate positions, intermediate results.